# std::vector with const pointer to const object does not compile

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, constants

I get a whole lot of errors from gcc when trying to complie this method. zones_ is a

```
std::map<int,std::vector<Zone const * const>>
```

That is a private member of MyClass.

```
//get unique zones
std::vector<Zone const* const> MyClass::getZones() const {
  std::vector<Zone const * const> zones; //why can I not do this???
  std::map<Zone const * const,int> zone_set;
  for(auto & pair : zones_) {
      for(Zone const * const z : pair.second) {
          if(zone_set.count(z) == 0) {
            zone_set[z] = 1;
            zones.push_back(z); //cannot do this
          }
      }
  }
return zones;
}
```

Can I have a vector of const pointers to const objects?

Comment: Can you post the errors? I'm curious about them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no, the element type cannot be const (can be pointer to const type though)

also there is no need for this, since when you return a const reference to your vector, the access to the elements will be const_reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator[]

Answer (score 3):

No. In general, elements of vectors can't be `const` since they have to be moved when the vector's array needs reallocating. You'll have to store `Zone const *`; or perhaps use a different container type (`list`, `deque` or possibly `set`), if you really need constant elements.